# Re-order the array order both key and value

Tags: php, arrays

Say I've got an array

```
[0]=>test
[2]=>example.
```

I want o/p as

```
[0]=>test
[1]=>example
```

In my first array

```
[1]=>NULL
```

I've tried to remove this and reorder so, I used `array_filter()` to remove the `null` value.

Now, how do I reorder the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you need, I think [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) should help (it will return only the values in the array, reindexed from 0):

```
print_r( array_values($arr) );
```

Here's an example of this: http://codepad.org/q7dVqyVY

Comment: :I want both key and values as o/p.

Comment: What does o/p mean? And how do you want both the keys and the values since in the array you write as example the key 2 is gone? PS: I've updated my answer with a link showing the code that seems to work the way you want it to.

Comment: Well, if you want the keys use array_keys (that will give you an array  like `array(0, 2, ...)`) and for the values you can use array_values as I've said. If you want both combined, you already have them in the original array. Just look at my codepad link and say what's wrong with my output.

Comment: @draevor the problem with your approach is that not removes `null` values as required.

Comment: @NomikOS The OP states he already used array_filter to remove the null values.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [merge](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php):

```
$newArray = array_merge(array(),$oldArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Array = array('0'=>'test,', '2'=>'example');
ksort($Array);
$ArrayTMP = array_values($Array);
```

or

```
$Array = array('0'=>'test,', '2'=>'example');
ksort($Array);
$ArrayTMP = array_merge ($Array,array());
```

Credit goes to: http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-17794.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = array(0 => 1, 1 => null, 2 => 3, 3 => 0);

$r = array_values(
        array_filter($a, function ($elem)
                {
                    if ( ! is_null($elem))
                        return true;
                })
);

// output:

array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 3,
  2 => 0,
)
?>
```

NOTE: I am using an anonymous callback function for array_filter. Anonymous callback only works in php 5.3+ and is the appropriate in this case (IMHO). For previous versions of php just define it as normal.